# Old sci fi (1980s or earlier) short story about androids sold as 'the perfect son in law' or 'the perfect housewife'

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have this memory of a short story I read as a child at school in the late 80s/early 90s. The story was written in the form of a catalogue, advertising these androids and talking about which model might fit into your life. I remember some of the names - one model was 'Sandra, the perfect housewife', and another was 'Patrick, the perfect son in law', with various references to the way the law had established these weren't people - the 'Sandra' who declared she wanted to be baptised wasn't permitted, a guerilla fighter who was a 'Patrick' was not executed, only 'erased'.

It was in a collection of short stories that was sold in paperback form, and was in my school library in Newbury, UK.